# Jira backup files being automatically created every 3 hours

Tags: backup, jira, scheduling

On my Jira server v7.5.2 (CentOS 7), in `/data/atlassian/jira/export`, there is a bunch of zipfiles created every 3 hours, each around 200 Mb in size:

```
...
2018-Aug-14-0000.zip
2018-Aug-14-0300.zip
2018-Aug-14-0600.zip
2018-Aug-14-0900.zip
2018-Aug-14-1200.zip
2018-Aug-14-1500.zip
...
```

Apparently they're automated backups.  However, there is neither any Scheduled Job nor any cron job with such a timing.

What could be creating these files? Is there any other Jira job scheduling or setting that I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Admin, System, Services. There is a Backup Service running there. You can edit or delete it there

Comment: But make sure you are backing up the database regularly and also the jira data.dir /data directory with the attachments